# Wrapping INSERT by BEGIN TRANSACTION and COMMIT

Tags: python, sqlite

I have some code from my class. It's about making one database from another. There is a INSERT method. It takes really long time. I read the FAQ, and i know that I need to put BEGIN TRANSACTION and COMMIT around the multiple INSERT, but i swear, I tried every place of c.execute(''BEGIN TRANSACTION") and c.execute("COMMIT") - always same ca 5 kb/s. Please show me where is the proper place for those instruction, or tell me what else could be a problem.

For the record - I'm working with 5400 RPM hard drive.

Here is original code:

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('/path/to/database.db')
c = conn.cursor()

with open('sqlite-sakila-schema.sql', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as create_file:
    create_query = create_file.read()
with open('sqlite-sakila-insert-data.sql', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as insert_file:
    insert_query = insert_file.read()

c.executescript(create_query)
c.executescript(insert_query)

conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

edited:
first file:
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/master/jOOQ-examples/Sakila/sqlite-sakila-db/sqlite-sakila-schema.sql

second one:
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/master/jOOQ-examples/Sakila/sqlite-sakila-db/sqlite-sakila-insert-data.sql

It is all about INSERTs. There is couple tables, whole sql file started with deleting from those tables, and then 231K lines of INSERTS code like below.

```
Insert into language
 (language_id,name,last_update)
Values
('1','English','2006-02-15 05:02:19.000')
;
Insert into language
 (language_id,name,last_update)
Values
('2','Italian','2006-02-15 05:02:19.000')
;
Insert into language
 (language_id,name,last_update)
Values
('3','Japanese','2006-02-15 05:02:19.000')
;
Insert into language
 (language_id,name,last_update)
Values
('4','Mandarin','2006-02-15 05:02:19.000')
;
```

Comment: Transactions won't make a query go faster.

Comment: @Barmar I think he’s suspecting that he has autocommit on, in which case it would make a difference. But if he’s not using autocommit, of course, just shuffling the location of the commit around won’t help…

Comment: Can you post a small sample of your `sqlite-sakila-insert-data.sql` file capturing the gist of it?

Comment: @abarnert Is it because commit performs an `fsync()` so there's no pipelining of all the `INSERT`s when autocommit is used?

Comment: @zwer It sounds like it's just a sequence of `INSERT` statements.

Comment: Does the insert file contain lots of separate `INSERT` statements, or one statement with lots of `VALUES` lists? The latter will likely be more performant.

Comment: @Barmar Most databases just store commits into some kind of journal off to the side, without inserting them into place; then, when you commit, it merges the whole thing in one go. And they can avoid locking (or checking optimistic locks) on each insert, only doing one lock/check when you commit. Sqlite3, being simpler than most databases, makes the difference even more extreme.

Comment: @abarnert What do you mean talking about autocommit. I thought if I commit the transaction, there is no point in autocommiting anything.

Comment: I thought you were worried about autocommit, because if you _are_ using autocommit, that could cause these performance problems. (Although the fix would be to change the isolation level or otherwise disable autocommit, not to add more transactions.) If you aren't using it, then you're not looking in the right direction at all; just adding an explicit transaction on top of the implicit one won't do anything.

Comment: From a quick glance at your schema, start narrowing thing down by (at least temporarily, for testing) removing all of your triggers, constraints, and indexes. If that speeds things up, then bisect the problem—add half of them to see if the problem comes back, then remove or add half of them, etc. until you've isolated the issue. (Then, if you don't know how to fix things without giving up something you need, you can ask for much more specific help.)

Comment: @Barmar added description of insert file

Comment: @bloniaq Auto-commit means that you don't use `BEGIN TRANSACTION;` or `COMMIT` explicitly, so the database automatically treats each query as a transaction. This can slow things down because it has to acquire and release locks between each query.

Answer (score 0):

Try combining your `INSERT` queries into a single query:

```
INSERT into language (language_id,name,last_update) VALUES
('1','English','2006-02-15 05:02:19.000'),
('2','Italian','2006-02-15 05:02:19.000'),
('3','Japanese','2006-02-15 05:02:19.000'),
('4','Mandarin','2006-02-15 05:02:19.000'),
...
;
```

SQLite has a limit on the size of a single query, which is the value of `SQLITE_MAX_SQL_LENGTH` and defaults to 1,000,000 bytes. So you'll need to either increase this limit or split this query up into groups that fit into the limit. Doing them in groups of something like 1,000 rows will probably make a noticeable difference.